# Read the cell value without opening the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set ObjWB = Workbooks.Open("c:\Test.xlsx")
```

If I used `workbooks.open` command, that Excel workbook opens.

I need without open that Excel workbook to read the cell value.

Comment: You cannot read a file without opening it. But you can open that file, read the values you need and close it.

Comment: If it is really something you need then search for "indirect.ext". Personally i'd open the workbook, retrieve the values, close the workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Peh and Zerk

Answer (score 0):

Run the Sub `GetValue` after setting the parameters in `ReadFromClosedWorkbook` (Workbook & Worksheet). You could pass either or both of them as arguments from the calling procedure.

```
Sub GetValue()
    Debug.Print ReadFromClosedWorkbook("A1")
End Sub

Private Function ReadFromClosedWorkbook(Target As String) As Variant

    Const WbFullName = "D:\My Documents\Your file name.xlsx"

    Dim PathName As String
    Dim WbName As String
    Dim WsName As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim Sp() As String

    WsName = "My Worksheet's Name"

    Sp = Split(WbFullName, "\")
    WbName = Sp(UBound(Sp))
    ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)
    PathName = Join(Sp, "\") & "\"
    If Len(Dir(WbFullName)) Then
        Target = "'" & PathName & _
                 "[" & WbName & "]" & WsName & _
                 "'!" & Range(Target).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
        ReadFromClosedWorkbook = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Target)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I got a answer ,i have added GetObject function to read the cell value without open the workbook  eg : Set ObjWB = GetObject("c:\Test.xlsx")

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I'm getting object error when running this code?